# How to form linear model from two data frames?

Tags: r, lm

```
MarriageLicen

   Year Month Amount
1  2011   Jan    742
2  2011   Feb    796
3  2011   Mar   1210
4  2011   Apr   1376


BusinessLicen

   Month Year MARRIAGE_LICENSES
1    Jan 2011               754
2    Feb 2011              2706
3    Mar 2011              2689
4    Apr 2011               738
```

My question is how can we predict the number of Marriage Licenses (Y) issued by the city using the number of Business Licenses (X)?
And how can we join two datasets together? 
It says that you can join using the combined key of Month and Year.

But I am suffering from this question for several days.

Comment: Is it correct to have a column `MARRIAGE_LICENSES` in dataset `BusinessLicen`?

Answer (score 4):

There are three options here.

The first is to just be direct. I'm going to assume you have the labels swapped around for the data frames in your example (it doesn't make a whole lot of sense to have a `MARRIAGE_LICENSES` variable in the BusinessLicen data frame, if I'm following what you are trying to do).

You can model the relationship between those two variables with:

`my.model <- lm(MarriageLicen$MARRIAGE_LICENSES ~ BusinessLicen$Amount)`

The second (not very rational) option would be to make a new data frame explicitly, since it looks like you have an exact match on each of your rows:

```
new.df <- data.frame(marriage.licenses=MarriageLicen$MARRIAGE_LICENSES, business.licenses=BusinessLicen$Amount)
my.model <- lm(marriage.licenses ~ business.licenses, data=new.df)
```

Finally, if you don't actually have the perfect alignment shown in your example you can use `merge`.

```
my.df <- merge(BusinessLicen, MarriageLicen, by=c("Month", "Year"))
my.model <- lm(MARRIAGE_LICENCES ~ Amount, data=my.df)
```